# Wordpress Multisite

Tags: wordpress

I have install wordpress multisite I have 4 other sites installed using master site

```
1 master 
   --subsite
   --subsite  
   --subsite
   --subsite
```

What i need to do is any post publish on **subsite** will be auto publish on **master site**

Thanks 
Gurpreet

Comment: I am planing to make a plugin

Answer (score 1):

You  need a Plugin for this, maybe this one can help:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-sitewide-tags/

Comment: how about the pages and comments??

Comment: That's another thing ;) You could either copy a Post to the Main Site, or just show the Post of the Subsite so that the Comments still belong to the Subsite. The Plugin will work for Pages, which is way different. So, you want a Copy, or you just want to Show the Post?